# how to repartition/refactor/ reduce chunks in timescale DB

Tags: timescaledb

Currently, I have a timescaleDB hyper table with 10GB space, however, I had partitioned it to 1500 chunks, on a machine with 32GB memory, I realized it is over-killing. I would like to ask what is the proper way to convert my hypertable to a table that has less chunks....

This was how I constructed my table previously:

```
CREATE TABLE db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand (
    symbol VARCHAR(32), 
    timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
    volume DOUBLE PRECISION, 
    close DOUBLE PRECISION, 
    high DOUBLE PRECISION, 
    low DOUBLE PRECISION, 
    open DOUBLE PRECISION
)

;
SELECT create_hypertable('db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand', 'timestamp','symbol',8);
```

I have created a new table trying to migrate data over

```
CREATE TABLE db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand2 (
    symbol VARCHAR(32), 
    timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
    volume DOUBLE PRECISION, 
    close DOUBLE PRECISION, 
    high DOUBLE PRECISION, 
    low DOUBLE PRECISION, 
    open DOUBLE PRECISION
)

;
SELECT create_hypertable('db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand2', 'timestamp','symbol',1,chunk_time_interval => INTERVAL '3 years');
```

shall i do?

```
INSERT INTO db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand2
SELECT * FROM db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently TimescaleDB doesn't provide any tool to convert existing chunks into different chunk size. So it is necessary to do it manually. I believe that the only way is to create new hypertable with the desire chunk size and then copy data from the old hypertable to the new hypertable. If necessary rename new table after dropping the old table.

The copy can be done through CSV file to utilize [Timescale's parallel copy tool](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-parallel-copy). Or it is good to insert in batches to improve copying performance.